# magento2 adding tab with content to offcanvas

Tags: magento2, navigation, mobile

I have been trying to create an additional tab in `navigation.sections` and insert inside languages, and my own account (complete with a menu), login, logout that I have created outside `header.links`, they work good on desktop but cannot manage to make them appear in navigation.sections ( the xml managing content of the offcanvas menu),

I have tried different approach, I have started with inserting just the customer.phtml, the latest is (in MyName/myTheme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml):

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="store.information" group="navigation-sections" template="Magento_Theme::html/container.phtml">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Information</argument>
            </arguments>
                <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Customer" name="store.settings.customer" template="Magento_Customer::account/customer.phtml">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="id_modifier" xsi:type="string">nav</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
                <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Login" name="store.settings.custom_customer_form_login" template="Magento_Customer::form/login_pop.phtml" >
                <arguments>
                        <argument name="id_modifier" xsi:type="string">nav</argument>
                    </arguments>
                        <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Login\Info" name="newpopup" template="Magento_Customer::newpopup.phtml"/>
                  </block>
                  <block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="store.settings.language" template="Magento_Store::switch/languages.phtml">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="id_modifier" xsi:type="string">nav</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
                <block class="Magento\Directory\Block\Currency" name="store.settings.currency" template="Magento_Directory::currency.phtml">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="id_modifier" xsi:type="string">nav</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>


        </block>
```

The result is all title to dropdownDialog are there, but the dropdwon itself is not present, even if the phtml called is already in the page and working under another layout name.

Comment: I think you are looking for tab in mobile view right?

Comment: Yes, there is where the offcanvas is.

Comment: Are you logged in?

Comment: I try both logged and not, no real difference

Comment: Actually if you check customer.phtml the codes says if customer logged in then it will show. Can you try to call different file instead of customer.phtml and paste some dummy content.

Comment: as said there is not real difference, the block outside the navigation div render with no problem while the one inside is incomplete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This finally worked

```
<referenceContainer name="page.top">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="navigation.sections" before="-" template="Magento_Theme::html/sections.phtml">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="group_name" xsi:type="string">navigation-sections</argument>
                <argument name="group_css" xsi:type="string">nav-sections</argument>
            </arguments>
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="store.menu" group="navigation-sections" template="Magento_Theme::html/container.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Menu</argument>
                </arguments>
                <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="Magento_Theme::html/topmenu.phtml" ttl="3600" before="-"/>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="store.information" group="navigation-sections" template="Magento_Theme::html/container.phtml">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Account</argument>
            </arguments>
            </block>


        </block>
        <container name="top.container" as="topContainer" label="After Page Header Top" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="top-container"/>
        <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Breadcrumbs" name="breadcrumbs" as="breadcrumbs"/>
    </referenceContainer>
```